# Get property of related/nested object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get a property of a related/nested object. A question object has many choices, and I want to return a certain choice with a `correct` field equal to True/1.

So I get the question by ID:

```
    $question = Question::find($request->get('id'));
```

Then get the related choice which has correct == 1:

```
    $answer = $question->choice->where('correct', 1);

    return $answer;
```

The response is an object within an array:

```
[
  2
   {
    "id": 3,
    "choice": "Non eos architecto ut.",
    "question_id": 1,
    "correct": 1,

   }
]
```

I wanted to access the choice field:

`return $answer->choice;`

But get this error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$choice

I tried using flatten:

```
 $answer = $question->choice->where('correct', 1)->flatten();
```

But all this does is remove the question ID `2`, but doesn't allow me access to the object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other answer if you want to retrieve just that one value from the database.

But it looks like you already retrieved all the answers as a [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) and want to filter that collection.

The `where` method returns another Collection. So to get just the one element, use `first`:

```
$answer = $question->choice->where('correct', 1)->first();
```

This gives you the actual Eloquent object

And then you can access any properties as usual.

```
return $answer->choice;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`value`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results) method to get a single value from the database:

```php
$choice = $question->choice()->where('correct', 1)->value('choice');
```

BTW, you should rename your `choice` method to `choices`, since it's a `hasMany` relationship.